# JDA cant find the gateway intents class

Tags: java, jar, discord, noclassdeffounderror, discord-jda

I have built my jda discord to a jar file and it raises the class not found error for the gateway intents class saying that its not found or this error specifically

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/GatewayIntent
        at banos.bot.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more
```

Edit: Here is my build.gradle if that helps.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version "7.1.0"
    id 'application'
}

group 'banos.bot'
version '1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

ext {
    javaMainClass = "banos.bot.Main"
}

application {
    mainClass = 'banos.bot.Main'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name 'm2-dv8tion'
        url 'https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases'
    }
    maven {
        name 'duncte123-jfrog'
        url 'https://duncte123.jfrog.io/artifactory/maven'
    }}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    implementation group: 'net.dv8tion', name: 'JDA', version: '4.3.0_324'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'me.duncte123', name: 'botCommons', version: '2.3.9'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'banos.bot.Main', 'Class-Path': './build/libs/Banos_Bot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your build configuration? (Maven or Gradle)

Comment: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/2%29-Setup

Comment: Redi I added my build.gradle to the original post